# Парсинг CSR библиотекой bouncy castle в С#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509

Есть необходимость проверять запросы на сертификаты(CSR).
Сам запрос раскладываю так:

```
    public static Pkcs10CertificationRequest Request (string request)
    {
        string selectedPath = Loader.requestDirectory.FullName + request;
        string csr = File.ReadAllText(selectedPath);

        char[] characters =
            csr.Replace("-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "")
            .Replace("-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "")
            .ToCharArray();

        byte[] csrEncode = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(characters, 0, characters.Length);
        Pkcs10CertificationRequest decodedCsr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest(csrEncode);
        return decodedCsr;
    }

Pkcs10CertificationRequest decodedCsr = Request(*сюда попадет сертификат выбранной из формы*);
CertificationRequestInfo requestInfo = decodedCsr.GetCertificationRequestInfo();
```

Проверка происходит сравнением данных в запросе и в шаблоне по определенным полям. В случае успеха во всех пунктах возвращается true, т.е. всё ок.
Проблема в том, что библиотека неоднозначно возвращает поля. Я увидел два способа:
1.

```
requestInfo.Subject.ToString();

//1.2.643.100.3=тут инн,1.2.643.100.1=тут огрн,1.2.643.3.131.1.1=тут тоже инн,E=мыло,C=RU,ST=78 г. Санкт-Петербург,L=Санкт-Петербург,O=название орг,OU=отдел,CN=имя,STREET=адрес и вот тут проблема(ниже опишу),GIVENNAME=Иван Иваныч,SURNAME=Иванов
```

Я сначала подумал, что можно сделать сплит по запятой, т.к. она есть после каждого поля, но в адреса может быть запись "улица, дом 55" - и тогда она тоже разобьет.
Тогда я решил сделать:

```
requestInfo.Subject.GetValueList();
```

Но в выводе я полую список ТОЛЬКО значений, без пояснения полей, т.к. метод реализуется через интерфейс IList, что в итоге тоже не применимо, т.к. не ясно какое это поле и что с ним сравнивать, т.к. `1.2.643.100.3` - может быть 10, а может 12. И если он вдруг окажется не первый в списке, или другие поля сдвинуться - получится беда.

Как выйти из этой ситуации? Или может не bouncy castle использовать? У кого был опыт работы с запросами, подскажите. Я ещё думал о том, чтобы перебор `Subject` сделать с реакцией на `=` и значением после. Типа:

- Берем набор символов до `=`
- Записываем в ключ
- Берем после `=` и до `=,`
- Записываем в значение
- и т.д.

Но это чет выглядит как-то убого. Может есть способ для идиотов вроде меня?

Comment: Зачем вы делаете .ToString(), если там наверняка есть коллекция oid'ов?

Comment: Да, там есть `Subject.GetOidList()` - но возвращает только сами OID без значения. Т.е. лист OID, как и называется метод. С крутил-вертел этот класс, но так и не нашёл метода, который бы возвращал коллекцию пар key-value. Могу предположить, что порядок значений в `Subject.GetOidList()` и `Subject.GetValueList()` совпадает - тогда можно было бы сделать это самостоятельно. Но кто знает...

Comment: Хотя. Это достаточно хорошая идея. Попробую, в ожидании возможных советов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал в итоге так:
Добавил метод расширения для `Subject`

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> SubjectFriendlyInfo(this X509Name subject)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> collection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        int valueCount = subject.GetOidList().ToList().Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++)
        {
            collection.Add(subject.GetOidList().ToList()[i], subject.GetValueList().ToList()[i]);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

В моих влажных мечтах он собирает пару ключ(OID)-значение(значение). Надеюсь я не наступлю на какие-нибудь грабли.

Comment: Не наступите: я поискал в доках про порядок полей. Утверждается, что порядок будет такой же, в каком встретятся OID'ы в строке.

Comment: `collection.Add(subject.GetOidList()[i].ToString(), subject.GetValueList()[i].ToString());`

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку.

Answer (score 1):

Подключил nuget в  linqpad, поковырял немного. Образца запроса нет, поэтому пример немного синтетический, взят из вопроса с [en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47986975/5752652):

```
string subject = "CN=Name,O=Org,C=IN,ST=KA,OU=OrgUn,PostalCode=560103";
X509Name sub = new X509Name(subject);
var oidList = sub.GetOidList();
var oidsVal = sub.GetValueList();

oidList.Dump();
oidsVal.Dump();
```

Выведет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример взят наощупь, но есть уверенность, что заработает, т.к. тип вашего `csr.GetCertificationRequestInfo().Subject` такой же - X509Name:

Кстати, и на ваших данных работает:

```
string subject = "1.2.643.100.3=тут инн,1.2.643.100.1=тут огрн,1.2.643.3.131.1.1=тут тоже инн,E=мыло,C=RU,ST=78 г. Санкт-Петербург,L=Санкт-Петербург,O=название орг,OU=отдел,CN=имя,STREET=адрес и вот тут проблема(ниже опишу),GIVENNAME=Иван Иваныч,SURNAME=Иванов";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В [описании методов](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/X509Name.html) написано, что порядок будет строго такой, в каком встретились в строке:

```
 getOIDs

    return a vector of the oids in the name, in the order they were found.

getValues

    return a vector of the values found in the name, in the order they were found.
```

Со словарём:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> SubjectFriendlyInfo(this X509Name subject)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var oids = subject.GetOidList();
    var vals = subject.GetValueList();

    var size = oids.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result.Add(oids[i].ToString(), vals[i].ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Я уже накидал метод расширения для создания dictonary, но это тоже попробую. Т.к. не знаю насколько правильно я сделал. Ниже в комментарии описал как. Спасибо.