# Парсинг и извлечение Extensions CSR библиотекой Bouncy castle в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Пишу проверятор запросов на сертификат, всё шло успешно, пока не появилась необходимость проверять разделы, которые у нас называются Расширения сертификатов. И туда попадают Использование ключа и Улучшенный ключ.

Как я понял, в этой библиотеке за это отвечает Asn1.X509.X509Extension. По крайней мере, как я прочитал в примерах и в документации - он позволяет создавать такие значения. Но я не понимаю как извлечь.

[Парсинг CSR библиотекой bouncy castle в С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979014/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-csr-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-bouncy-castle-%D0%B2-%D0%A1)

Вот тут я извлекаю поле subject. Как таковые я их вижу. Если вытащить
    public static Pkcs10CertificationRequest Request (string request)
    {
        string selectedPath = Loader.requestDirectory.FullName + request;
        string csr = File.ReadAllText(selectedPath);

```
    char[] characters =
        csr.Replace("-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "")
        .Replace("-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "")
        .ToCharArray();

    byte[] csrEncode = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(characters, 0, characters.Length);
    Pkcs10CertificationRequest decodedCsr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest(csrEncode);
    return decodedCsr;
}

Pkcs10CertificationRequest decodedCsr = Request(*сюда попадет сертификат выбранной из формы*);
CertificationRequestInfo requestInfo = decodedCsr.GetCertificationRequestInfo();
var attr = requestInfo.Attributes;
```

То в этих атрибутах будет:

```
[1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14, 
    [[[2.5.29.15, TRUE, #030204f0], 
    [2.5.29.37, #306006082b0601050507030206082b060105050
```

Что соответствует OID для Расширения сертификатов(1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14) , использование ключа(2.5.29.15) и улучшенный ключ(2.5.29.37). Но я не пока вижу ни одного способа превратить `2.5.29.37, #306006082b0601050507030206082b060105050` в:

```
 Улучшенный ключ (2.5.29.37) Не критическое
      Неизвестное использование ключа (1.2.643.3.6.1.6)
      Проверка подлинности клиента (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
      Защищенная электронная почта (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4)
      Пользователь Центра Регистрации, HTTP, TLS клиент (1.2.643.2.2.34.6)
      Неизвестное использование ключа (1.2.643.3.6.3.3.5)
      Срок действия сертификата 12 месяцев (1.2.643.3.6.0.12)
```

Помогите советом куда копать.
Ключ

```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```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сертификат внутри закодирован ASN1 кодировкой. Некоторые элементы внутри так же могут быть закодированы. `Extended Key Usage` это один из таких примеров. Код ниже выводит все OID'ы для вашего примера:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var decodedCsr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest(Convert.FromBase64String(@"
        MIIEczCCBCACAQAwggGpMRYwFAYFKoUDZAMSCzAwMDAwMDAwMTAxMRgwFgYFKoUDZAESDTM0MDAw
        MDAwMDAxMTExGjAYBggqhQMDgQMBARIMMDA3NzQ1MzA4MjAyMR0wGwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg5pdmFu
        b3ZAbWFpbC5ydTELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxLTArBgNVBAgMJDc4INCzLiDQodCw0L3QutGCLdCf0LXR
        gtC10YDQsdGD0YDQszEmMCQGA1UEBwwd0KHQsNC90LrRgi3Qn9C10YLQtdGA0LHRg9GA0LMxIDAe
        BgNVBAoMF9Ce0J7QniAi0KDQvtC80LDRiNC60LAiMSAwHgYDVQQDDBfQntCe0J4gItCg0L7QvNCw
        0YjQutCwIjElMCMGA1UECQwc0YPQuy4g0JLRi9C80YvRiNC70LXQvdC90LDRjzEwMC4GA1UEDAwn
        0JPQtdC90LXRgNCw0LvRjNC90YvQuSDQtNC40YDQtdC60YLQvtGAMSIwIAYDVQQqDBnQmNCy0LDQ
        vSDQmNCy0LDQvdC+0LLQuNGHMRUwEwYDVQQEDAzQmNCy0LDQvdC+0LIwZjAfBggqhQMHAQEBATAT
        BgcqhQMCAiQABggqhQMHAQECAgNDAARA/nUiC5yMyPYwZ+E66umAitfnRjYua9RP8J9fp6foE/UZ
        4ZO8dJjhbPkf0oGpfg4i1dxdvsMc3OcUZNqkDjgvc6CCAgQwGgYKKwYBBAGCNw0CAzEMFgo2LjIu
        OTIwMC4yMIG+BgorBgEEAYI3AgEOMYGvMIGsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIE8DBCBgNVHSUEOzA5Bgcq
        hQMDBgEGBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwQGByqFAwICIgYGCCqFAwMGAwMFBgcqhQMDBgAMMDYG
        BSqFA2RvBC0MKyLQmtGA0LjQv9GC0L7Qn9GA0L4gQ1NQIiAo0LLQtdGA0YHQuNGPIDQuMCkwHgYJ
        KwYBBAGCNxUHBBEwDwYHKoUDAwYDDAIBAQIBADCCASMGCisGAQQBgjcNAgIxggETMIIBDwIBAx52
        AEMAcgB5AHAAdABvAC0AUAByAG8AIABHAE8AUwBUACAAUgAgADMANAAuADEAMAAtADIAMAAxADIA
        IABDAHIAeQBwAHQAbwBnAHIAYQBwAGgAaQBjACAAUwBlAHIAdgBpAGMAZQAgAFAAcgBvAHYAaQBk
        AGUAcgOBkQAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwCgYIKoUDBwEBAwIDQQAUExYf
        FFBntIlJWVl3YLB/4qTtpBRoMWWtpnHy45HlC0+p7HZyLLd+wngM+FEkNYkifM53eoEq/IvMAKlA
        /VoO"));
    var requestInfo = decodedCsr.GetCertificationRequestInfo();
    var extendedKeyUsage = requestInfo.Attributes
        .Cast<DerSequence>()
        .Where(seq => seq.Count >= 2)
        .Where(seq => seq.Cast<Asn1Object>().First() is DerObjectIdentifier)
        .Where(seq => seq.OfType<DerObjectIdentifier>().First().Id == "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14")
        .Select(seq => seq.OfType<DerSet>().First())
        .Select(set => set.Cast<DerSequence>().First())
        .SelectMany(seq => seq.Cast<DerSequence>())
        .Where(seq => seq.OfType<DerObjectIdentifier>().First().Id == "2.5.29.37")
        .First()
        .OfType<DerOctetString>()
        .First()
        .GetOctets();

    var parser = new Asn1StreamParser(extendedKeyUsage);
    IAsn1Convertible obj;
    while ((obj = parser.ReadObject()) != null)
    {
        var seq = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(obj);
        foreach (var oid in seq.Cast<DerObjectIdentifier>())
            Console.WriteLine(oid.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мужик, как же ты хорош. Я всё пытался осилить перевод примеров такого разбора на java под С#. Но ты меня спас. Спасибище!